# How do I PERMANENTLY prevent applications from taking exclusive control of an audio device?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm running Windows 10 64 bit. Have been for years. For years this problem has plagued me and it's time to find a way to be rid of it once and for all.

The problem is that certain applications, such as Netflix or Movies & TV or some websites, will take "exclusive control" of my audio output. The fact that this is even possible for an application to do is frustrating beyond belief. I can stop this behavior temporarily by opening the Sound control panel, going to the properties of the output (or input) device, selecting the Advanced tab, and unchecking the box to "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device".

The problem is that this checkbox keeps getting re-checked at apparently random intervals. I don't know exactly when it happens or what is doing it; perhaps it's Windows updates, perhaps it's Store App updates. The only way I have to discover that exclusive control has been re-allowed is to open up an app and discover that all the audio for everything else I do on my computer is suddenly broken.

I need a way to prevent this checkbox from being reset.

[image: Screenshot of audio device properties]

Comment: Just curious: What's the problem with that?

Comment: @PMF - I multi-task. If I am working and need to hear my VoIP phone ring and I opened Netflix during lunch, if this box is checked Netflix takes exclusive control of my audio and I can't hear my phone ring. If I watched a movie last night and left the Netflix app open, I can't hear a youtube video or a video game or anything else. If I pause my movie in TV & Movies to switch back to another task, I can't hear notifications and alerts.  There is no legitimate use case for this setting ever.

Comment: I see, yea that is annoying. I can't tell for sure, but there's probably a way an application can set this value. But then, I would expect that it happens only after using a particular App.